# GooglePlayService AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, adview

I'm trying to include ads in my application, i have created AdMob account, followed tutorial (downloaded API, Imported google-play-services/libraries/google-play-services_lib into workspace, in Java Build Path/Libraries i have imported google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services, and checked field in Java Build Path/Order and Export

in my project i did

Layout activity_menu

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       />
```

java file

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
     AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

When i Run my application i can see the ads are showing up, but i got few warnings

```
01-10 12:29:04.269: W/dalvikvm(2450): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 35
01-10 12:29:04.289: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2450): Google Play services is missing.
01-10 12:29:15.319: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2450): Google Play services is missing.
```

and error

```
01-10 12:29:15.359: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2450): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 1
```

So, despite of the error i get, i have seen my ads several times, but when i check on AdMob account it says i got 0 views. Is it becouse i have not published my app yet, or maybe i have to do something more? Whats that error about?

EDIT:
AdMob site refreshed and now i see 45 my views but no money accounted for that, are these ads PPC or in a test mode? Can i change them to PPV somehow?

Comment: did you added the right AdMob key?

Comment: you mean ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"?
i put the whole thing with my publisher id

Comment: yeah that should be the Unit Id, but its not that much long string.

Comment: My AdMob account says 
"Identyfikator jednostki reklamowej: ca-app-pub-3231742841852835/8488524303"
i know that ca-app-pub-3231742841852835 is my publisher number, so should i cut it down to 8488524303 only?

Comment: Oh, AdMob site refreshed and now i see 45 my views but no money accounted for that, are these ads PPC or in a test mode? Can i change them to PPV somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats the exact problem in your case, but I did the following and its working fine.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "a152c65f562hc48b");
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView); //layout is a RelativeLayout.
        // // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```